# Can one provide an answer in need of a question?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Is there a  preferred manner in which to provide answers to questions that have not been asked yet? This may be information that I believe may help somebody else.  I know I can post my question and then answer it appropriately but want to follow best practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best practice is to ask your question and answer it. See our [help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) for more information regarding this.

> If you have a question that you already know the answer to, and you
>   would like to document that knowledge in public so that others
>   (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly okay to ask and
>   answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Be advised that the normal quality rules still apply. I've seen people on Stack Overflow post some pretty terrible questions to go with their answers.

Comment: Understood.  Thanks for the advice.